# how to fetch id from MenuItem in Menu

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, fetch

[Table Ui with menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPAp6.png)

The edit button of all the users are fetching only the last user id

it worked if it's not nested inside the menu just displays as an edit button but whenever it's nested inside the Menu it's only fetching the last id of the user

Here's the code

```
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);                                                                                                                
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

    
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

//TableCell Code

<StyledTableCell align="left">
              <Tooltip
                    title="Update and Delete"
                    id="basic-button"
                    aria-controls={open ? "basic-menu" : undefined}
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded={open ? "true" : undefined}
                    onClick={handleClick}
                    value={user}
                    arrow
              >
                <MoreHorizIcon  value={user}/>
             </Tooltip>
             <Menu
                id="basic-menu"
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                open = {open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                getContentAnchorEl={null}
                value={user}
                anchorOrigin={{vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'center'}}
                transformOrigin={{vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'center'}}
            >
              <MenuItem  value={user.id} onClick={()=> navigate(`/edit-users/${user.id}`)}>
                <ManageAccountsIcon sx={{ margin: "1vh" }} />
                        Edit
              </MenuItem>

              <MenuItem value={user.id} onClick={() => 
  handleDelete(user.id)}>
                <DeleteOutlineIcon sx={{ color: "red", margin: "1vh" }} />
                         Remove
               </MenuItem>                   
            </Menu>
</StyledTableCell>
```

[Code for menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLZO7.png)

I want to fetch the id of the same user

Comment: Is this Menu element inside map?

Comment: @VasuAwasthi yes it's inside map and worked fine if i displayed it without menu options

Comment: Code seems fine, does open update the selected user or does  anchorEl={anchorEl} element always open the last menu items.
Including more files will help  in identifying the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try another approach in selecting the user

```
  // use useRef if its causing to many re-renders
  const selectedUserIdRef = React.useRef()

  const handleClick = (event, userId) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    selectedUserIdRef.current = userId;
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
     selectedUserIdRef.current = null
  };

  const onNavigate = () => {
     // try catch and checks
     if (selectedUserIdRef.current) {
       navigate(`/edit-users/${selectedUserIdRef.current}`)
     }
  }
 
  const onDelete = () => {
     // try catch and checks
     if (selectedUserIdRef.current) {
      //deleted with selectedUserIdRef.current
     }
  }

  //TableCell Code
 const TableCellComponent = (props) => {

  // second option set an anchor element for cell 
  //const anchorElRef = React.userRef()

  ... 
    <Tooltip
       title="Update and Delete"
       id="basic-button"
       aria-controls={open ? "basic-menu" : undefined}
       aria-haspopup="true"
       aria-expanded={open ? "true" : undefined}
       onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, user.id)}
       value={user}
       arrow
       ref={anchorElRef}  // second option
     >
        <MoreHorizIcon  value={user}/>
     </Tooltip>

     <Menu
            id="basic-menu"
            anchorEl={anchorElRef} // second option
            open = {open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            getContentAnchorEl={null}
            value={user}
            anchorOrigin={{vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'center'}}
            transformOrigin={{vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'center'}}
        >
          <MenuItem  value={user.id} onClick={onNavigate}>
            <ManageAccountsIcon sx={{ margin: "1vh" }} />
                    Edit
          </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={user.id} onClick={onDelete}>
                <DeleteOutlineIcon sx={{ color: "red", margin: "1vh" }} />
                         Remove
               </MenuItem>                   
            </Menu>
```

I dont really understand why anchorEl is not get set, and it showing the last element

check the tooltip [onOpen](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tooltip/) event, you can set the userId there

but I hope this helps you in someway

Comment: I'm getting correct id on click event function but on setSelectedUserId(userId) the selecteduser is the previous one user mean for id 4 it's 3 and if i used setSelectedUserId(null) the selectedUser always null

Comment: I think passing the right element ref could work, 
but I modified the example to user selectedUserIdRef instead of useState, its not an ideal solution but hope its take you closer to finding the right solution

Comment: Glad it helped, but if you can, try to find a better solution

Comment: i'm unable to figure out what's going wrong but i'll try

Comment: Great, you can upvote then answer if you feel it helped...